# Error when deleting foreign key

Tags: sql

For a table copy script to another database, I want to drop a table to recreate another with news elements.
To do that and after try to use Microsoft helps, I use this command to disable constraint key on my table and after drop it :

```
USE MDE_DOS_DEMO_GH;
GO
ALTER TABLE MDE_DOS_DEMO_GH.dbo.PMEELEMENT NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
GO

DROP TABLE MDE_DOS_DEMO_GH.dbo.PMEELEMENT;
```

I've this error when I drop my table :

```
Imposible to delete PMEELEMENT object because ... FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT
```

Have you an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: I've forgotten to say Hello everybody

Comment: The error message should tell you which foreign key constraint is the problem.  That constraint will exist on another table, and refer to the table you are trying to drop.

Comment: As @MatBailie says, the key here is that the constraint is on *another* table *referencing* the one you are trying to drop.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.